# How to compile java gdal PGEO on apple silicon MacOS to read mdb file?

Tags: java, macos, ms-access, gdal

I installed `unixodbc` and `mdbtools` through `Homebrew`, and all dependences of `gdal`.

my cmake configure is following:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/yuziqun/main/software/gdal-3.8.4-nokml -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=/Users/yuziqun/main/software/gdal-3.8.4-nokml/lib -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=OFF -DGDAL_USE_LIBKML=OFF -DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_Arrow=ON -DPGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE="DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=%s" ..
```

and I get some information and one warning:

```bash
➜  gdal-3.8.4 mkdir build
➜  gdal-3.8.4 cd build
➜  build cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/yuziqun/main/software/gdal-3.8.4-nokml -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=/Users/yuziqun/main/software/gdal-3.8.4-nokml/lib -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=OFF -DGDAL_USE_LIBKML=OFF -DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_Arrow=ON -DPGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE="DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=%s" ..
...
...
-- Found ODBC: /opt/homebrew/lib/libodbc.dylib  found components: ODBCINST
...
...
-- Configuring done (16.1s)
-- Generating done (0.8s)
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE


-- Build files have been written to: /Users/yuziqun/main/temp/gdal-3.8.4/build
➜  build cmake --build . -- -j6
➜  build cmake --build . --target install
```

I don't know why the `PGEO_DRIVER_TEMPLATE` is not used.

Then I copied `libgdalalljni.dylib` and placed it in `/Library/Java/extensions`.

Then I get an error while running a Java program:

```java
gdal.AllRegister();
System.out.println(gdal.VersionInfo());
Driver driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("PGeo");
DataSource ds = driver.Open("/Users/yuziqun/main/temp/640122HLX_2006Y00_SV050_P.mdb", 0);
System.out.println(ds);
```

```
3080400
ERROR 3: Cannot open file '/etc/odbcinst.ini'
ERROR 1: ODBC: MDB Tools driver not found!

ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for /Users/yuziqun/main/temp/640122HLX_2006Y00_SV050_P.mdb,

null
```

Then I went to find `odbcinst.ini`. In the end, I copied `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini` from the `/opt/homebrew/etc` directory to the `/etc` directory, and edited the `odbcinst.ini` file as follows:

```ini
[Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
Description = MDB Tools ODBC drivers
Driver     = /opt/homebrew/lib/libmdb.dylib
Setup      = /opt/homebrew/lib/libmdb.dylib
FileUsage  = 1
CPTimeout  =
CPReuse    =
```

But I still got an error:

```
3080400
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for /Users/yuziqun/main/temp/640122HLX_2006Y00_SV050_P.mdb,

null
```

I want to know which step I made an error in, could you please help me.

I have tried many methods, and I hope my program can run normally. I hope I haven't missed any details from the official document :) .